# No WebRTC relay ICE candidates returned using TURN over TLS with coturn

Tags: webrtc, coturn

Ubuntu server 20.04

Coturn-4.5.1.1

SSL certs generated with certbot

Chrome/Firefox

EC2

`/etc/turnserver.conf` as follows.

```html
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=443
external-ip=[MYEXTERNALIP]
min-port=49152
max-port=65535
verbose
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
server-name=turnserver
user=[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]
realm=[MYDOMAINNAME]
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[MYDOMAINNAME]/fullchain.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[MYDOMAINNAME]/privkey.pem
no-rfc5780
no-stun-backward-compatibility
response-origin-only-with-rfc5780
```

Using [Trickle Ice](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/):

`stun:stun.[MYDOMAIN]:3478` gathers `rtp host` and `rtp srflx`

`turn:turn.[MYDOMAIN]:3478?transport=tcp` with username and password gathers `rtp host` and `rtp relay`.

`turns:turn.[MYDOMAIN]:443?transport=tcp` only gathers `rtp host`.

I assume that this means that because no relay ICE candidates are returned for `turns:turn.[MYDOMAIN]:443?transport=tcp` that TURN over TLS will fail. Port 443 is open on the firewall.

There are no errors being logged. Coturn status looks fine.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Can you check turn:turn.[MYDOMAIN]:443?transport=tcp  I mean not turns but turn

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this and just did so again and it makes no difference, unfortunately.  Still no relay candidates returned.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes in your configuration and it should work

1. external-ip=public-ip/private-ip
2. relay-ip=private-ip(EC2)
3. listening-ip=private-ip(EC2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).